# Voltage Drop due to inrush current

Tags: transient, inrush-current, voltage

When an air-conditioner is switched on, light bulbs in the house flicker a little.  I was told that this is due to the inrush current of the ac. I am assuming that voltage drop is causing the flickering.
Why does this voltage-drop occur? Does it have to do with the long transmission lines? 
Does this voltage drop happen even when a normal electrical appliance (like another bulb) is switched on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does this voltage-drop occur? Does it have to do with the long transmission lines?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqM4RT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A simple model of the generation, transmission and utilisation of an electrical supply.*

Yes. The transmission line has some resistance (R1) as well as some inductance (L1). Both of these will cause an increasing voltage drop along the line in proportion to the current drawn.

When R2 is switched on it forms a potential divider and, ignoring inductance for simplicity, the voltage at the house will be given by
$$ V_h = \frac {R_2}{R_1+R_2}V_1 $$
To maintain a steady voltage at the house R1 needs to be kept low relative to the maximum load (minimum resistance) of the load in the house.

The situation is aggravated by sharing the supply with several other buildings on your street.

> Does this voltage drop happen even when a normal electrical appliance (like another bulb) is switched on?

Yes, but for small loads (high R2) R1 becomes proportionally less significant and the voltage drop won't be noticeable.

> When an air-conditioner is switched on, light bulbs in the house flicker a little.

The main component of your air-conditioning unit is the motor. Motors draw increasing current with increasing load. That means that as you slow them down the current increases. The worst moment is on switch-on when the motor draws up to ten times the current it draws while running. This momentary high load is what causes the voltage to sag.

Comment: So the voltage is restored as steady-state is reached right?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to address that. See the added last paragraph.

Comment: How would I connect 10 air-conditioners if I did want to? Or if there are 10 houses around me and all of them have an ac(net resistance of R2/10) running, would there be a constant voltage drop in the 11th house?  Would there be a constant voltage drop if there is an electrical appliance that draws 10 times the steady current of ac? From the idea of voltage being divided it's clear that there will be constant voltage drop. But there are house that use a lot of power and still have flickering right?

Answer (score 0):

Your air conditioner has a **compressor** in it that compresses the refrigerant to allow it to pump heat from indoors to outdoors. The compressor is driven by a motor which draws significantly more current when it is powered up from a stationary state, but only for a brief time.

The lights flicker because the series resistance of the wires and source impedance of the mains (including the distribution transformers and so on) drops more voltage when more current is drawn.

Notice that the lights "flicker" from the start-up current surge- they do not (should not!) dim noticeably during continuous operation of the A/C compressor.

It tends to cause visible flickering in particular with incandescent bulbs because the light output is very sensitive to voltage- a slight drop in voltage results in a relatively large drop in (visible) light emission, however if the voltage drop is deep enough it can affect CFL, fluorescent and LED bulbs. The flickering can be minimized relatively economically by having the A/C on a separate electrical circuit from the lights, since much of the voltage drop will typically occur in the wiring after it leaves the distribution panel.

Comment: So if I assume the inrush current to be 10 times the steady current, then will there be a constant voltage drop if there is an electrical appliance drawing 10 times the steady current of the ac?

Comment: @ArunT For a while. If there was an appliance drawing the same as the inrush current in a steady manner, the fuse or circuit breaker would probably blow.

Comment: Assuming the current surge at the beginning is 10 times the steady state  current in air conditioners. If a house has registered for the power of 10 air-conditioners, then the house can draw 10 times the steady current, right? And now if only one ac is switched on will there still be a momentary voltage drop?

Comment: The wires in the circuit are sized for the steady-state current draw, not for surges. If your central air draws 25A the wiring will not be good for 250A, maybe the entire entrance panel will be (in total), but not the circuit wiring. Which is why most of the voltage drop is in the wiring of the individual circuit. The circuit breaker is sized to not blow during the start-up surge, but to blow before the wires get too hot if overloaded steadily (also to open quickly if the circuit is actually shorted).

Answer (score -1):

When current begins to flow when a motor kicks on, its basically briefly shorting your power supply voltage from the utility to ground (... or at least trying to). Since a short, by definition, has no voltage across it, your house's voltage sags, causing your lights to dim.